# How to send spring-graphql client subscription ping messages

Tags: spring, graphql, ping, subscription, spring-websocket

I'm using the spring framework's [spring-graphql library](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/reference/html/#client.subscriptions) to create a graphql client, as per the docs. When connecting to the server using a websocket for subscriptions, everything works fine for 5 minutes but then the websocket times out and disconnects. It turns out the server requires the client to send a ping message to keep the websocket alive. This is a graphql ping message as specified in the [graphql-ws protocol](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md)

I've checked in the docs and had a dig around in the code but can't see any way to send this ping message via the spring graphql client. Apollo client has similar functionality to what I'm after via a "keepalive" option in the graplq-ws [ClientOptions](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions.md#keepalive). Is there any equivalent I can use via spring or alternative way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to do this so raised an issue on github, and subsequently a PR with some changes to add basic support for sending pings.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/pull/608
and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/605